# How to find port on windows (using pid or processes name)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I know the PID, but I need the port on which the processes are running.

specifically want only the port of a processes, I know the name and PID of that processes, how to find the port

Comment: try (as admin) `netstat -abno | findstr <PID>` . then just look at the ports where the PID matches the last column of the output.

Comment: Thank you so much...... TCP 0.0.0.0:81 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 5424 I am getting this kind of result which is ok, but I want that port only, what to do for it

Comment: if you only want the first port opened by that process, you could use `((Get-NetTcpConnection -OwningProcess 5424 )[0]  | select LocalPort ).LocalPort`

Comment: also if you want only listening ports (I saw your other question this evening) you can filter the get-nettcpconnection call with `-state Listen` to get only listening ports ((Get-NetTcpConnection -OwningProcess 4 -state Listen)[0]  | select LocalPort ).LocalPort

Comment: @FrankThomas .... All that smells like an answer. I see no close votes on this questions so probably worth adding an answer. Tag me back if you decide to do so I can change my comment upvotes over to the answer. Also, Frank Thomas is the better actor per the Total-T commercial: https://vimeo.com/498078988....................                    
   |:::( : - } )--|===<

Answer (score 1):

Below are a couple of example one-liners and their outputs using PowerShell. You might find useful as a starting point.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "LISTEN" } | select @{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}}, localaddress, localport

Process     localaddress   localport
-------     ------------   ---------
services    ::                 49671
jhi_service ::1                49669
spoolsv     ::                 49668
svchost     ::                 49667
svchost     ::                 49666
wininit     ::                 49665
lsass       ::                 49664
svchost     ::                  7680
System      ::                   445
svchost     ::                   135
System      127.0.0.1          53106
System      127.0.0.1          53100
services    0.0.0.0            49671
spoolsv     0.0.0.0            49668
svchost     0.0.0.0            49667
svchost     0.0.0.0            49666
wininit     0.0.0.0            49665
lsass       0.0.0.0            49664
NordPass    127.0.0.1           9213
Discord     127.0.0.1           6463
svchost     0.0.0.0             5040
System      192.168.68.114       139
svchost     0.0.0.0              135
```

Second example including the start time of the process that is listening on the port and a filter for the process name.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "LISTEN" } | select @{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}},owningprocess, localaddress, localport, creationtime | where Process -eq "svchost" | Format-Table -AutoSize

Process owningprocess localaddress localport creationtime
------- ------------- ------------ --------- ------------
svchost          2856 ::               49667 18/02/2023 14:23:44
svchost          1536 ::               49666 18/02/2023 14:23:44
svchost          3428 ::                7680 20/02/2023 20:24:43
svchost          1160 ::                 135 18/02/2023 14:23:43
svchost          2856 0.0.0.0          49667 18/02/2023 14:23:44
svchost          1536 0.0.0.0          49666 18/02/2023 14:23:44
svchost          8332 0.0.0.0           5040 20/02/2023 20:24:43
svchost          1160 0.0.0.0            135 18/02/2023 14:23:43
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one cmdlet with a pipe to look for a specific PID:

```
netstat -ano | findstr PID
```

replace the word PID with the PID that you want to check.